# Denmark/Greenland: Entering the EU without crossing a national border

Tags: customs-and-immigration, eu, denmark

Greenland is a part of Denmark, but it is not a part of the EU. At Copenhagen airport customs is arranged to distinguish "Domestic/EU" arrivals and "Non-EU" arrivals. As non-EU, domestic arrivals which lanes should we have used, and which regulations followed?

Comment: We were faced with these two lanes at the airport. One of them may well have been some kind of bypass lane, but wasn't obviously so. The Air Greenland flight arrives at the international terminal, so it's set up for that, mainly.

Comment: I suspect that you should have used the non-EU channel and simply explained yourself if anyone questioned you.

Comment: Did your luggage tags have a green border?

Comment: Unrelated, FYI only: which airport in Greenland?

Comment: Kangerlussuaq, on our way to Ilulisat, for our honeymoon, many years ago. Here in the UK the whole EU and Schengen thing is big at the moment, and so this came up in a conversation, and it got me to remember the quandary the two of us were in at the time.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big enough strip to handle anything. I'm familiar with Narsarsuaq etc, hence my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Danish customs law considers Greenland and the Faroe Islands to be "third countries" ([Toldloven](https://www.retsinformation.dk/forms/r0710.aspx?id=16986), §1(3)), so by arrival in Denmark proper from one of these territories you should behave as an arrival from outside the EU, as regards customs.

Comment: So for customs reasons it is as if we had come from abroad, but for immigration, it was domestic (because it's in Schengen?)

Comment: @DanSheppard: Actually it's not in Schengen either -- but there are special provisions in the Danish accession treaty saying that there are no border controls between Schengen and Greenland / the Faroes _anyway_. So the flights behave as domestic nevertheless (even though, say, Schengen visas are not valid for Greenland).